# how to validate a file is Proper CSV or not in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a APi which receives CSV files as `IFormFile` . I have to check if the sent file is a proper CS file or not. So i am doing below checks.

1. Checking the File Extension.
2. Checking the File content type.

Issue:- If any app will use the API, then it's feasible to change the file extension along with the content-type. So how to validate a proper CSV file? I didn't get any helpful article as of now.

e.g. a PDF file can be changed to a .CSV(in extension) file along with its content-type. But PDF file is not a valid CSV

NB:- Magic number is one of the process for .XLSX,.docx,.pdf etc.But for CSV its not applicable, tried the same & failed. Any other way to check it?

Comment: Define "*proper CSV*" - do you mean RFC 4180?

Comment: a PDF file can be changed to a .CSV(in extension) file along with its content-type. But PDF file is not a valid CSV

Comment: Define "*Valid CSV*" is `a,s,d` a valid csv?

Comment: yes, its a valid CSV. i am not concern about the data. It's mostly about the file type. with above 2 check , easily user can bypass the validation check by changing the file extension & content-type.

Comment: So basically you care only if it's a file containing text? The delimeter and column count is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes. Because a PDF can't hold data shape like CSV.  As per @aybe we can use any Parser. but as i commented if the File is proper the Parsers will work perfectly, so i don't have to worry much about the data, as parser will handle those.

Answer (score 0):

**Closest you can get would be a robust `TryParse` method.**

But instead of re-inventing the wheel, try first a few libraries, they might do the job:

https://github.com/TinyCsvParser/TinyCsvParser

https://github.com/nreco/csv

Note that CSV parsing can be [a difficult task](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/08/04/csv-parsing-in-net-core/) even though it's a simple format.

Even if you can't use a library, there are plenty of ideas you can grab from them.

If I were to detect CSV content, I'd do the following:

- ensure that a line contains **readable** characters

  - optionally detecting file enconding might help
- ensure that a line isn't incredibly long, else it's likely to be **binary**, see #1
- detect that first line has **repeating** separators
- try parse lines

More or less this:

- find 1st index of CR/LF or LF
- read up to that
- find separators in it
- try parse the rest of the file, check against column count

  - if it fails then it's probably not CSV

It's pretty much all the heuristics you can try unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: I have already tried CSV helper, but the issue is, In my case there is not a fixed template will come, it can be any CSV. In the CSV helper/Tiny CSVParser, i tried passing a Pdf file(with csv extension &  content-type as of CSV), the these helpers start reading out of the parsing value(foul values i.e. !@#@##)  special characters.  its ideally not validating the file. its simply parsing anything to CSV

Comment: Seems Tough though i can give a try to this.

Comment: Shouldn't be terribly difficult to try IMO.